# Multiple Array Value on CollectionView - Swift

Tags: swift

I pull data from the database. The data I have captured is more than one in the array (you can see it in the photo below). I transfer this data to swifte. Since there is more than one data while transferring to the swif, I throw the data into the array. But while Array has to show the data inside it as a variable by throwing a comma, it prints all of them side by side like a single variable. For this reason, only one data is added from 3 data should be added. How can I show multiple data in collectionView?

output article1: `detayTaxItem(aciklama: ["Adres1"], baslik: [".."], fiyat: ["01"], adet: ["11"], tarih: ["2020-02-25 22:092020-04-25 22:09"])`

For example, it has to assign the date variable to two separately, while assigning it to a single array.

[webservices output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xExyV.png)

As you can see when Webserv is available, there are two different data. I want to show these two different data in CollectionView.

```
struct detayTaxItem {
    let aciklama: [String]
    let baslik: [String]
    let fiyat: [String]
    let adet: [String]
    let tarih: [String]
}

class TaxTableViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!
    let keychain = KeychainSwift()

    var items = [detayTaxItem]()

       var formAdıSoyadı : [String] = []
       var formAcıklama : [String] = []
       var formFiyat : [String] = []
       var formADET : [String] = []
       var formTARIH : [String] = []
       var formMUSTERIID : [String] = []


    @objc func mustBILGICEK(){

               ...
      do {
           if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                  for review in baslik {
                    if let soru_baslik = review["ADRES"] as? String {
                        let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.formAcıklama.append(s)
self.collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0)) } } } }

          if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
              for review in baslik {
                if let soru_baslik = review["ADI_SOYADI"] as? String {
                     let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                         DispatchQueue.main.async { self.formAdıSoyadı.append(s) self.collectionView.reloadData() } } } }


            DispatchQueue.main.async {

              let article1 = detayTaxItem(aciklama: [self.formAcıklama], baslik: [self.formAdıSoyadı], fiyat: [self.formFiyat], adet:[self.formADET],tarih:[self.formTARIH])
                  self.items = [article1]
                                } } catch let parseError {
                                 print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
                                 let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                             }
                         }
                         task.resume()
                 }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mustBILGICEK()
}
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellGecmis", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewTaxCell
...

 else {
            let article = items[indexPath.row]
             cell?.altIsım.text = "\(article.baslik)"
             cell?.altPriceLabel.text = "\(article.fiyat)"
           }


        return cell!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge array item into single string like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellGecmis", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewTaxCell {
    ...

    else {
        let article = items[indexPath.row]
        cell?.altIsım.text = (article.baslik.map{String($0)}).joined(separator: ",")
        cell?.altPriceLabel.text = (article.fiyat.map{String($0)}).joined(separator: ",")
    }
    return cell! 
}
```

Comment: Yes it works smoothly. I want the formTARIH to sync the date variables in the webservice to individual arrays while append.

Comment: @horusss Can you show me design, How do you want to show data on Collection View.

Comment: TARIH output: ["2020-02-25 22:09", "2020-04-25 22:09"] I printed it as, but when I make self.items = [article1], the null value is returned, it does not print the data.